# 30Bees/Presta 1.6 shop translation in frontController

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add a few translations to the frontend of our module. When the translations are in the .tpl files they do get rendered. However no translation fields get shown in the backend my code for the .tpl files is:

```
{l s="Text" mod="myModule"}
```

I also do need to do some translating in the FrontControllers (mainly Error handling and feedback for serverside validation).

In the AdminController I simply use `$this->l('Text');` which works. However, in the FrontController this is not available. I've checked the ControllerCore and FrontControllerCore, `l()` is not defined in those and only available in AdminController.

Can anyone give me a detailed explanation of what I need doing? All my research on the web always points to `$this->l()` being the thing to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using translations in tpl files you need to use single quotes not double quotes.

```
{l s='Text' mod='myModule'}
```

As for front controllers... well if you're using custom module controllers as in controllers that extend `ModuleFrontController` you can use

```
$this->module->l('Text');
```

And if you're not using those controllers then... start using them.

Some things might be different since thirtybees is a fork of PrestaShop but I guess translation mechanism is the same.

Comment: Thanks, the single quotes work. I am currently working up rethinking my ajax/controller setup to make it work with ModuleFrontController. But isn't there an easier way to maybe use translations outside of controllers as well?

Comment: Well you can also pass instance of your module to some class outside controllers, but then you need to use `$module->l('text', 'classname')` so that backend translator finds the string. I'm gonna guess that you're building ajax processing/responses outside controllers like some old PS modules do. Use controllers for ajax just as you would for normal module pages. This is how you keep MVC, have all the PS methods like translations and also internal hooks fire as they should allowing other modules to handle them properly.

Comment: Yes, I am just adding translations to a somewhat old-ish module. There will be a time for a rework, but it has not yet come. The `$module->l` works, but even when I put a classname, it is not found for the backend translation for some reason

Comment: $module->l did not work for me because as it is my habit I used double quotes in php. Didn't realize the translation engine needs single quotes with their php functions as well, very odd.

Comment: It's because backend translator reads files and uses regex to pull texts to translate by matching stuff like `{l s=''}` and `->l('')`:) So if you use double quotes the regex ignores it.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense once you think about it. I just never saw it mentioned anywhere before.